# How can I exclude only recursive children of specific node in css selector?

Tags: css, select, xpath, css-selectors

PLEASE, Help with selecting the specific case.

I have one DIV with id='map-container', there are different other elements in this DIV.

MY GOAL IS: Using CSS, select COMPLETELY ALL THE ELEMENTS in my HTML, except all the children of this DIV with id='map-container' (recursively).

So, if I have for example:

```
<body>
<div ...>
 some other divs
</div>
<div ...>
 some other divs
</div>
<div ...>
 some other divs
</div>
[<div id="map-container">
 some other divs
</div>]
</body>
```

ONLY PART, THAT IS IN [ ] SHOULDN'T BE SELECTED.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I think `body :not(#map-container *)` should work

Comment: @AlonEitan, sorry bro, not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro, you just need not to exclude this elements, you just can override style you need with "unset" value. Maybe this will help.

```
#map-container * {
    css-style: unset;
}
```